# Confused on getting started as an ISV

Tags: isv, second-generation-packaging, environment-hub

I started following the ISVForce quick start [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv_intro_quickstart.htm). This guide seems out of date and not entirely accurate.

The first step is to register in the partner community. When I did this I received credentials for an organization with the environment hub installed. What is the purpose of this organization?

The second step in the guide wants me to create a developer org. This is where I begin to get confused.

I am aware that second-generation packages do not require a packaging org. Do I still need to make this org if I intend to use 2GP?

The third step wants me to create a Partner Business Org where I can access the LMA and COA.

However, the org that was given to me when I signed up in the Partner community already has the LMA installed. Do I need to do this step? The org given to me doesn't have the COA though?

Another question is which org do I enable the dev hub and 2nd generation packages?

Comment: I found this video by Salesforce Developers helpful. https://youtu.be/PsjfNAfbSbc

Comment: @HaroutTatarian I appreciate the comment but that's not very helpful

Comment: Lol I can tell you one useful thing. At my workplace our org where we have our environment hub and the LMA org are one and the same.

Comment: Now that's useful. But I'm still unsure where the COA is in my org

Comment: That’s the first time I hear of that since I’m not evolved in that process but I’m almost certain that would be in the same org since we only have one “business” org and the rest are development related.

Comment: https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Channel_Order_App

Comment: If you do an Internet search you will find information out there about this. For example, your PBO can (and should) be used as your company's CRM to track opportunities and leads. It is also your LMO, Environment Hub and Dev Hub (for the latter, this provides far higher limits on scratch org creation and activity, plus provides free access licenses for developers). Another thing to do is to search and utilise the partner forums. You will get direct help from Salesforce staff if you do.